# My application on the heroku server stops after running for 1 minute (PYTHON)

Tags: heroku, bots

My application on the heroku server stops after running for 1 minute. Then it runs and hears commands sent to itself whenever it wants. I was wondering if it could be from the 30-minute limit, but it never worked that long.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import commands as c

TOKEN = "--------------"

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    #my commands
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", c.start_command))


    #while I write unknown word that the bot doesnt know
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, c.wrong_command))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#commands.py

```
from telegram.ext import Updater


def start_command(update, context):
     message = "hi!"

     return update.message.reply_text(message)

def wrong_command(update, context):
     message = "/start only"

     return update.message.reply_text(message)
```

requirements.txt
"""

```
python-telegram-bot
```

Procfile

```
web: python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

""" There are not many codes in the "signs".